# How to center Text Under iFrame when text is wrapped around it

Tags: html, css, django, format

I have my iframe floating left and text wrapped around it. I'm trying to put text under it aligned center but everything I've tried seems to not work or mess the whole format up.. I have the code and preview here. https://codepen.io/Religion/pen/QWydbow. and what's on codepen below . Thanks!

```
<style>
 .container p {
  font-size:1.2rem;
 }

.container {
  height:100%;
  max-height:100%;

}



</style>


<div class = "container">

   <iframe style = "float:left;margin:5px 25px 0 0;margin-bottom:20px;  width:350px; height:300px;" src="https://embed-fastly.wistia.com/deliveries/7f74ec7de31d90e32a1d465fcebc1d0e12a27d18/file.mp4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>


<h2 class = "all-headings">Periodontal Maintenance</h2>
<p><strong>Periodontal diseases are infections of the gums, which gradually destroy the support of your natural teeth.</strong> There are numerous disease entities requiring different treatment approaches. Dental plaque is the primary cause of gum disease in genetically susceptible individuals. Daily brushing and flossing will prevent most periodontal conditions.</p>
<br>
<h2 class = "all-headings">Why is oral hygiene so important?</h2>

<p>Adults over 35 lose more teeth to gum diseases, (periodontal disease) than from cavities. Three out of four adults are affected at some time in their life. The best way to prevent cavities and periodontal disease is by good tooth brushing and flossing techniques, performed daily.</p>

<p>Periodontal disease and decay are both caused by bacterial plaque. Plaque is a colorless film, which sticks to your teeth at the gum line. Plaque constantly forms on your teeth. By thorough daily brushing and flossing you can remove these germs and help prevent periodontal disease.</p>
<br>

<p>Periodontal diseases can be accelerated by a number of different factors; however, it is mainly caused by the bacteria found in dental plaque, a sticky colorless film that constantly forms on your teeth. If not carefully removed by daily brushing and flossing, plaque hardens into a rough, porous substance known as calculus (or tartar).</p>

<br>


</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to add a center-aligned caption beneath the iframe that is separate from the main wrapped content? Or you are trying to center the main content beneath the iframe?

Comment: center-aligned caption beneath iframe ^^

Comment: wrap the `iframe` in a `div` and add your float syles to the `div`. Then put your `iframe` in the `div` and add text below it and add `text-align: center` to the wrapping `div` styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you wrap the iframe in a div and give it a sibling caption?

```css
.iframe-wrap {
float:left;
margin: 20px;
width:200px; 
height:150px;
display: block;
}
iframe { width: 100%; }
.caption { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="iframe-wrap">
   <iframe src="https://embed-fastly.wistia.com/deliveries/7f74ec7de31d90e32a1d465fcebc1d0e12a27d18/file.mp4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="caption">The caption!</div>
  </div>
  
  <p>Polaroid direct trade 90's migas green juice ugh selvage chambray freegan literally try-hard drinking vinegar franzen church-key dreamcatcher. Air plant selfies waistcoat activated charcoal crucifix literally flexitarian. Blue bottle poke kombucha lyft, shoreditch flexitarian offal 3 wolf moon 8-bit. Sustainable vegan pabst affogato, banjo kombucha poutine direct trade jianbing. Lomo wolf fixie YOLO. Vinyl gochujang freegan synth gluten-free ugh, flexitarian cold-pressed cray offal tote bag.</p>
  <p>Polaroid direct trade 90's migas green juice ugh selvage chambray freegan literally try-hard drinking vinegar franzen church-key dreamcatcher. Air plant selfies waistcoat activated charcoal crucifix literally flexitarian. Blue bottle poke kombucha lyft, shoreditch flexitarian offal 3 wolf moon 8-bit. Sustainable vegan pabst affogato, banjo kombucha poutine direct trade jianbing. Lomo wolf fixie YOLO. Vinyl gochujang freegan synth gluten-free ugh, flexitarian cold-pressed cray offal tote bag.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: wrapping it a div and styling accordingly worked perfect. After seeing solutions I see it was a silly question. Thanks all^^

Answer (score 0):

You put the iframe in a row and full col-md-12 so it will make it full width alone and you display it as flex so you can justify it in center. Then the text you put a div with a class of text-center and you close the div down till you done with the text you want to be centered. Before that you must add 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">` in your header.

```
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12" style="display:flex; justify-content:center">
       <iframe style = "float:left;margin:5px 25px 0 0;margin-bottom:20px;  width:350px; height:300px;" src="https://embed-fastly.wistia.com/deliveries/7f74ec7de31d90e32a1d465fcebc1d0e12a27d18/file.mp4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      </div>

    <div class="text-center">
    here goes the text below the iframe
    </div>
```

Comment: This relies on bootstrap. Is OP using bootstrap?

Comment: Just FYI: adding the entire Bootstrap css file is probably overkill if you are only using it here. But fire away if you want to use it elsewhere in the project.

Comment: Who doesnt use bootstrap nowdays bro, ease your code with just one link stylesheet.